# Setting up private multiple public/private Git repositories with Apache and mod_macro

Tags: git, apache

I have always been running SVN repositories on my private server. I had a few projects to maintain, all are maintained using a standard configuration pattern that came to be used as an Apache `macro`. Basically my structure is pretty straightforward

- https://svn.example.org

  - /svnroot

    - /repo1
    - /repo2
  - /viewvc

    - /repo1
    - /repo2

Mapped on

- /home/me/srv/svn/repos

  - /repo1
  - /repo2

There are multiple macros, because each repository has its own authentication scheme (public read, authenticated commit or completely private)

### Now I want to go to Git

Even if I have found a few configuration directives for using Apache and Git, I haven't understood them correctly. Following is my question:

---

I want my virtual host (`https://git.example.com`) to host multiple Git repositories, all configurable with ease from shell (e.g. adding a `mod_macro`'s `Use` directive and running `git init` via SSH). Each one having its own permission system, e.g. according to `.htpasswd`. A typical repository path can be `https://git.example.com/[projects-or-whatever]/myProject.git` mapped to somewhere like `/home/me/srv/git/repos/myProject`

**How to do that in Apache?**

---

#### So far so bad

I tried to build a Git configuration like the following (not yet tested as it won't do a thing for now)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName git.example.com
    ServerAlias www.git.example.com
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    AssignUserID me myself

    # Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=500000000"

    ErrorLog /path/to/error_log
    CustomLog /path/to/access_log "vhost_combined"

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/default

    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    #SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to.ca-bundle
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLProxyEngine on

    #Used for system login instead of .htaccess
    AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/bin/pwauth
    SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe

    <IfModule mime.c>
        AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert      .crt
        AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl         .crl
    </IfModule>



    ScriptAliasMatch \
       "(?x)^/git/(.*/(HEAD | \
       info/refs | \
       objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
       [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
       pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
       git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
       "/usr/lib/git/git-http-backend/$1"

    ScriptAlias /git /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/me/srv/git/repos/
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL


    #In this directory, specific repositories are configured
    Include "/home/hosting/vhosts.d/me/git/*.git.conf"

    <Directory "/home/me/srv/git/repos">
        Allow from all
        Options +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>


    <Directory "/usr/lib/git/">
        Options ExecCGI Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi

    <Files gitweb.cgi>
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

But let's focus on the following line that I can't understand right now

```
 ScriptAliasMatch \
       "(?x)^/git/(.*/(HEAD | \
       info/refs | \
       objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
       [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
       pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
       git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
       "/usr/lib/git/git-http-backend/$1"
```

From my [understanding](https://www.regex101.com/r/kL6nY8/2) the above regex matches absolute paths like

```
/git/sdf/HEAD
/git/blablabla/blabla/objects/info/sdfs
/git/daf/git-receive-pack
```

Ok, looks like that all of my projects will be placed under `/git/` if I don't change that, **is that correct**?

But then, since I don't currently know how the Git over HTTP protocol works, **how do I secure each repository independently from the others**?

Comment: That configuration is a gitweb configuration. It allows me to display Git repository in a fancy way, not to push. For pushing, I should investigate WebDAV or Smart HTTP (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging [the book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) might provide the answer. Here is the candidate answer before I try it.

Basically the above global configuration tells that everything ending with the given pattern (e.g. `git-receive-pack`) is sent to the Git CGI. OK.

But using proper `LocationMatch`, `Alias` and `<Directory>` directives should work. Here is a draft:

- Use `Alias` to map a file system directory to a location
- Use `<Directory>` to set up `.htaccess` if needed. SVN used `HTTP verbs` to distinguish read/write operation, Git uses `git-receive-pack` for writes. The book suggests using a `LocationMatch` directive
- Wrap everything in a `Macro`