# Using a Git manager against existing private Git repositories

Tags: git

This question is tied to [my other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769326/setting-up-private-multiple-public-private-git-repositories-with-apache-and-mod), but it's a different question in the specific.

Suppose I have already set up private Git repositories in Apache 2 within an organization. Later we decide to implement a Git management tool such as [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash) or just *any* other. AFAIK these tools come with their own Git server, or at least I haven't performed research yet.

The question is very simple: can Stash, or another tool, be set up in order to work on existing URLs instead of relocating the repositories? I'm asking now because my organization is planning to use Git and we must decide our strategy in advance. Stash is current candidate because we use other Atlassian products.

The scenarios are two: either we start our own "manual" `Git`ting on our Apache "monstre" (using the same approach I'm going to use for my personal private repositories) and then buy Stash when we like, or we must buy Stash first.

The distributed nature of Git suggests that repositories might be migrated to another URL easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/198428/answers/4265130), unfortunately Stash cannot be used to just put access control on top of an existing Git repository. You have to [import your "vanilla" Git repository to Stash](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54235/answers/3034326).

Regarding other tools, [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) (which I highly recommend) can put access control on top of an existing Git repository. It works with both [HTTP](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/http.html) or [SSH](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html) access to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by setting up a Git repository in Apache 2. Git is a server by itself and does not need Apache to run. Looking at your other question, maybe Apache is only to get a view of the repository and navigate it remotely? Or is it to be able to clone through http? Or more than that?

Stash will be hosting your git repositories by itself. You can use it to manage permissions, code reviews...etc...

As you mention in your last line, it is easy enough to "move" (clone) a git repository from one place to another, so if you have a system that works now and you just decide to use Stash, gitolite, github or anything else later, that should not be a problem. It's more about the services you want or use around that git server that you may have to change.

Comment: The other question is about running the git server on port 443, possibly inside the Apache process. **Exactly** like you do with SVN over HTTP (https://www.csoft.net/docs/svndav.html)

Comment: @djechelon, perhaps doing things with Git "exactly" like you do them with Subversion isn't the right approach? They are different tools, and assuming that Git should work like Subversion will be confusing and misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Gitolite is great if you want centralized control of users, permissions, etc. For a bit more flexibility, delegating management of individual (groups of) projects to users, via a web interface, I recommend gitlab (https://about.gitlab.com), basically an open source altrnative to github written in ruby/rails.

Comment: GitLab is also great, but AFAIK it requires relocating repositories so that GitLab itself hosts them.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by relocation and hosting,  yes, in the same way as gitolite does. Gitlab is quite similar to gitolite,  the main difference is that there is a Web interface for managing keys, access, etc., instead of text files. We use it as it separates the management of the server itself from that of individual git repos.